# there is no webpack.mix.js file in my laravel project root

Tags: laravel, webpack, tailwind-css, laravel-mix

my laravel version is 9.22.1

I want to install tailwindcss in Laravel.

Do I have to manually install webpack and laravel-mix?

Comment: Laravel does not come with mix anymore, the link to this in their documentation if you want to use mix: https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix . Easy to migrate back to mix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [laravel-mix documentation (v2.1 Installation)](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/2.1/installation#installation) has an info-box with an exclamation mark pretty high up at the beginning of the document (!):

> You won't find a `webpack.config.js` file in your project root. By default, Laravel defers to the config file from this repo. However, should you need to configure it, you may copy the file to your project root, and then update your `package.json` NPM scripts accordingly: `cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js ./` .

Comment: webpack.config.js is not webpack.mix.js This is not the answer